# I have Asterisk 11 installed and is working Fine with Dahdi, to I need to reinstall asterisk and dahdi if I want to add ss7?

Tags: asterisk, ss7

I have Asterisk 11 installed and is working Fine with DAHDI

I need to add ss7 support to DAHDI and asterisk, do I need to reinstall Asterisk and DAHDI with a version that support ss7 ?

or I just have to install ss7 lib and Asterisk and DAHDI  will support ss7 automatically ?

Regards

Comment: This question should probably be moved to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: You should rebuild. For some cards you should patch asterisk

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to rebuild dahdi. Altough you will need libss7 from Digium/Asterisk, compile and install it. Then Asterisk should be reconfigured (using ./configure in the source directory), look for ss7 during the process. Then asterisk can be rebuilt. When chan_dahdi.so get's linked, sig_ss7.o will be linked in.